# Как отключить знаки экранирования в python?

Tags: python-3.x, экранирование

Есть примерно такой html код

```
<div>
бла бла бла <img class="c1" src="https://vk.com"> бла бла. 
<div>
```

Нужно записать этот код в массив. Но при попытке чтения html кода через f.read(), возникает такая ошибка

```
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Вот код:

```
import io
import re

def getQuestArr(fname):
    findStr = "Вопрос: (.*)"
    text_arr = []
    f = io.open(fname, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    text = f.read() 
    f.close()

    result = re.finditer(findStr,text)
    for match in result:
        text_arr.append(match.group(1))
    return text_arr 

fname = "bla.txt"
arr1 = getQuestArr(fname)
```

Содержание файла bla.txt

```
Вопрос: <div>бла бла бла <img class="c1" src="https://vk.com"> бла бла. <div>
```

Comment: уберите `encoding="utf-8"` или скажите как вы записываете все в файл

Comment: Возможно, у файла кодировка cp1251, попробуйте вместо `encoding="utf-8"` указать `encoding="cp1251"`. Кст, 1) вместо `io.open` можно просто `open` вызывать -- это встроенная функция, тогда `import io` можно убрать. 2) если файл открывать в конструкции `with`, то и `f.close()` убрать 3) `text_arr` можно заполнить в одну строку: `text_arr = [match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(findStr, text)]`

Comment: Проблема решена благодаря Twiss.